# Knowing when a virtual machine will be restarted automatically

Tags: google-cloud-platform, virtual-machine

Is it possible in google cloud platform, know in advance (like some weeks) that a VM will be restarted due maintenance?

We have found that it is possible to get this information requesting metadata like 60s before...

But we are running long executions (of 2-3 weeks) in GPU, and this maintenances restarts are a pain for us...

Thank you very much in advance.